# Can I delete Long Running Operation Status list items?

Tags: list, performance, splongoperation

I support a SharePoint 2007 based public internet site that has a few performance problems. I just noticed that the hidden "Long Running Operation Status" list has nearly 10000 items in it. I can't imagine these are all still needed, I'm thinking I can delete all items where the status field is set to 'Successful'. However, I'm not sure what ramifications this may have.

Has anybody encountered this issue and/or done anything with this list?

Comment: Why do you think cleaning up this list will help the performance problems? If this is a hidden list then SharePoint should have a mechanism to clean it up automatically after so many days.

Comment: Some of the performance problems are around the creation of new sub sites which I believe are long running jobs. I'm not proposing that this is the answer to all problems but it looks like an issue to me. I also would have thought that SharePoint should clean this list up. So the fact that is isn't is either a problem with my environment, or a general shortcoming.

Answer (score 1):

This really falls into the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" category. The "Long Running Operation Status" list is hidden and managed by SharePoint. **As the list isn't explicitly exposed via the UI or through an API, you run the risk of making your farm unsupported by messing with it.** Most of the problems around performance and lists with many items are caused by when those lists are queried, and that isn't happening here.

It would be better to focus on the specific performance issues you are experiencing or checking places where errors are logged such as the ULS or Windows Event Log rather than worrying about this list.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that the list gets purged weekly. I agree with Alex on areas to concentrate for performance issues. However we've done all that already and are clutching at straws to get better performance. Thanks.